# How to divide an integer by a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, division

```
sample = [['AAAA','BBBB','CCCC'],['BBBBB','FFFFF','GGGGG'],['AA','MM']]
```

I need to calculate 'a' such that a = summation 1/i; where i ranges from 1 to n-1. In the process, I need to divide an integer (MyInt) by a list.

```
i2 =[]
afinal =[]
for sub_list in sample:
    i1 = range(len(sample[0]))
    i1.pop(0)
    myInt = [1 for x in i1]
    newList = [float(int1)/float(x) for int1,x in zip(myInt,i1)]
    a = [sum(i) for i in zip(newList)]
afinal.append(a)
print afinal
```

However, I get the output as [[1.0]], whereas I should be getting an output with as [1.83333333333, 2.08333333333,1] numbers within a list.

Any idea where I may be going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "divide an integer by a list"?

Comment: I am dividing an integer (Here 1) by a list of numbers. So I need to return a list where 1 is divided by each element in the list

Comment: Dividing an integer by a list makes no sense.  What you actually seem to want to do is divide an integer by each item in a list and put the results into a new list.  Also your newList = [myInt/x for x in i2] is iterating over i2 which is an empty list [] defined on your first line so of course newList will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have made changes in the program. But it still seems to have issues when i do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to calculate 'a' such that a = summation 1/i; where i ranges from 1 to n-1

```
>>> n = 5
>>> a = sum(1.0 / i for i in range(1,n))
>>> a
2.083333333333333
>>> 1./1 + 1./2 + 1./3 + 1./4
2.083333333333333
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes! That helps a lot. Let me check if that works in a loop

Comment: why does it not work here? https://eval.in/673136. I feel like I am missing something obvious

Comment: Python 2 division defaults to integer division if two integers are involved.  Make sure one of them is a float if you want float division, or use `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to divide `a` by every element of your list.
What you need is `reduce`:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
reduce((lambda x, y : x/y), l)
```

Will return the first element of `l`, which is `1`, divided by all the other elements of `l`.

**Explanation**

`reduce` applies the first parameter to the first two elements of the second parameter, and repeats it with a new list whose first element is the result of the call, and the other elements are the elements of the passed list, started from the 3rd, until the second parameter has only one element.

Example call to clarify:

```
>>>reduce((lambda x, y : x+y), [1, 2, 3])
step 1: 1+2=3, so the new call is reduce((lambda x, y : x+y), [3, 3])
step 2: 3+3=6, so the new call is reduce((lambda x, y : x+y), [6])
step 3: [6] has only one element, so returns 6.
```

`lambda x, y : x/y` means "you know, that function that takes two arguments and that returns their quotient". This is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about (Integer division). I would prefer using Numpy. Following might be what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])     # a List
b = 3                         # INT Value
print b/a
```